# How to convert Triangle/OBB test to OBB/OBB test?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, bounding-boxes

I'm using the collision library OZCollide and I want to do OBB vs. OBB collision tests. The problem is, that this function doesn't seem to exist but instead there is a AABB vs. OBB and a Triangle vs. OBB function. I'm not very comfortable with OBB intersections, but I think the necessary code is already there!

Can anyone help me by using this code for OBB/OBB Testing?

[The code is here.](http://pastebin.com/6T3HT8gD)

This code doesn't belong to me, It's Igor Kravtchenko's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert one of the OBBs to an AABB by applying the inverse of the first OBBs transform to both OBBs.

Now the first OBBs is an AABB and the other is still an OBB, so you can use the AABB vs OBB function to test if they overlap.

If the collision function returns a normal/position, you must transform them by the fist OBBs transform to put them back into world space.